# Looking for specific bearing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, bearings

I am new to mechanical engineering so I don't know the terms for different bearings.

I'm trying to make a honey extractor. I have a rotating basket made out of stainless steel that is going a maximum of about 100 RPM. Through the center of the basket, I have a 1/2 inch rod going vertical. I want to figure out a good stand for this rod to rotate on. The basket needs to be taken out since the whole unit needs to be cleaned after use. Everything needs to be stainless steel or at least food grade.

I don't know what kind of bearing to set it on. I initially thought of a transfer bearing but they look like they are very expensive for one that can hold the weight of the basket plus honey frames, about 200 lbs.

I also considered putting it on a large ball bearing in a cup but I don't know how I could build it to make the ball bearing stay in the right spot.

I also considered just having the rod rotate on a stainless steel plate but I am not sure if 200 lbs will wear on the surface over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that mass, use a large diameter roller bearing supporting the drum directly - just like the lazy susan rotating serving plates used at table.

Of course, if you want a low friction bearing then a circular mercury bath is also a solution - used in some lighthouses to get a very smooth rotation for the lenses around the light. But purchasing that amount of mercury might be costly, let alone the permits to have it as the Health & Safety Police may be all over you like flies around dogs xxxx. And as you are dealing with food...